# Using ack, how do you display one page at a time?

Tags: linux, ack

I would like to use ack and have the results shown one page at a time.

I've already tried to pipe it to |more, but this removes the color formatting. I would like to keep the colors intact.

Answer (score 2):

if you read man page of ack, you will see there is an option `--pager` for your needs. for example:

```
ack --color --pager=more ....
```

Comment: Thank you Kent. I totally missed that. However, I'm getting some strange output: ESC[1;32mItCommon/Config/cdpdr.iniESC[0m
ESC[1;33m18ESC[0m:ESC[30;43mmemcacheESC[0m = 10.133.182.11:11211:1ESC[0mESC[K

Answer (score 1):

Add `--color` to your call to ack.