# How to get sift to use a pager?

Tags: pager, sift-tool

I recently stumbled upon [sift](https://sift-tool.org/) ("A fast and powerful alternative to grep."). I quite like its feature-set, but there's one thing I'm missing: **paged output** (with colors).

I mean, it can be done:

`$ sift 'search_string' --color | less --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`

The `--color` I can put into **.sift.conf**, but the `| less -R` I have to repeat for every invocation.

With ack, I can stick this into the **.ackrc** and forget about it ([Using ack, how do you display one page at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672484/using-ack-how-do-you-display-one-page-at-a-time) / http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/).

How do I do this with sift?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/users/4535174/svent knows the answer to this one?

Comment: Also, I'd like to create the tag `sift-tool` for this, but I'm not allowed to.